# Selenium works a few times on linux but when trying again i get error "DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist"

Tags: python, linux, selenium

I am running the following selenium driver on linux. it works a few times then i get the "DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist error". If i turn off the instance and back on, it works again once or twice then gets back to this error. any suggestions?

```
    co = Options()
    co.add_argument("--log-level=3")    
    co.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    co.add_argument('headless')
    co.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    co.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
    co.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    co.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
    co.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    prefs = {"download.default_directory" : r'/home/marchenrisaad/algo_trade/data/'}
    co.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
    chromedriverpath = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriverpath, options=co)
    driver.get('https://tradingview.com/')
    #driver.maximize_window()
```

Comment: maybe you should use `driver.close()` at the end

Comment: @furas i 100% agree, thought that was the issue. but what do you do if the code runs an error in the middle and doesnt reach driver.close()? if i run again the old one is still open. what do you suggest?

Comment: python has `try/except` to catch errors. But some errors may need to change code because browser/selenium may work different then you expect - but it may need to show FULL error message in question and code which makes this problem